# How I guarantee a graphviz cluster is ALWAYS on the end?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I looked here in many other questions, but none of them do what I want, some rely on messing with lots of settings totally unrelated to the cluster itself, and hoping it will end where you want.

Basically I want a cluster to be the last one, no matter what, like the "rank=sink" option would do to a node, but to a cluster.

How I do that without resorting to mininum length edges and other ugly hacks?

EDIT: end I mean the end of the graph, the bottommost item on the default direction, or rightmost item in the LR one.

Comment: Sorry, the end of what?  A diagram or .gv file would help me understand.

Comment: clarified with an edit

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of anything as nice as rank=...  However,  This works pretty well:

- Embed "everything else" within a (new) cluster.  add peripheries=0 if you like
- Create 1 or more invisible edges from nodes near the bottom of the "everything else" cluster to nodes near the top of the "end" cluster

  digraph {
    subgraph cluster0{
      peripheries=0
      a->b->c->d->e->f
    }
    subgraph cluster1{
      x1->x2
    }
    f->x1 [style=dashed ]
  }